# React testing library using beforeAll to render cannot find item on 2nd test

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

The first tests passes.

The 2nd one I get error:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, waitFor, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';

import WrapProvider from '__tests__/__utils__/WrapProvider';

import PageMovies from 'src/pages/movies/index';
import { dataTestid as dataTestIdMoviesCount } from 'src/components/Specific/Movies/MoviesCount';
import { dataTestid as dataTestidDropdown } from 'src/components/Specific/Movies/SearchMovies/DropdownMovieGenres';

describe('<PageMovies>', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    render(
      <WrapProvider>
        <PageMovies />
      </WrapProvider>
    );
    await waitFor(() => screen.getByTestId(dataTestIdMoviesCount)); // success
  });
  describe('onload', () => {
    it('Should have search results', () => {
      expect(screen.getByTestId(dataTestIdMoviesCount)).toHaveTextContent(/ [1-9]/); //success
    });
  });
  describe('dropdown and search', () => {
    it('Should have dropdown', () => {
      const $dropdown = screen.getByTestId(dataTestidDropdown); // <- error - not found.
      // userEvent.selectOptions(screen.getByTestId(dataTestidDropdown), '28');
      // expect((screen.getByLabelText('Action') as HTMLOptionElement).selected).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
});
```

> error: TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="movies-dropdown"]

Yet this element does exist on the page onload

```
<div name="genre" style="width:400px" data-testid="movies-dropdown" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" class="ui compact fluid multiple search selection dropdown">
```

Am I using screen.getByTestId correctly?
It seems there are 3 ways to use this.
Which is the right way?

- `import { getByTestId } from '@testing-library/react';`
- `const { getByTestId } = render(<MyComponent/>);`
- `import { screen } from '@testing-library/react'; screen.getByTestId()`

Comment: Looks like you've correctly used it (*based on previous usage*). Are you certain of the exported/imported `dataTestidDropdown` value being used in the test? What if you hardcode the id, i.e. `screen.getByTestId("movies-dropdown");`, does it work then?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes certain. As you can see the test is showing it can't find it. 
[data-testid="movies-dropdown"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is an answer you need:
https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/541#issuecomment-562601514

According to this comment all you need to do is changing import:
`@testing-library/react` to `@testing-library/react/pure` to skip a cleanup after each test.

Comment: Apologies for delay in ticking this answer. I am actually surprised by this default to reset render between tests. It makes the beforeAll and beforeEach more troublesome. I don't know any other testing framework which does this so this is a rare discovery. In fact it makes me wonder if automated tests in general for front end are always pushed back because e2e tests are time expensive, and 'react-testing-library' being the only efficient equivalent begins with an opinion of wrapping all tests into one it statement per render.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps dropdown is not appearing on initial load, you could `findByTestId` (which is a promise which searches for 1000ms)

Ideally you want to use the returned function from `render()`. There are a few exceptions such as when a `React.portal` is used.

In fact, you want to refrain from using `data-testid`, it's best to search through what a user can access, such as accessibility roles/name and text.